# Need help to plot Talbot's Contour (Newbie question)

Tags: plotting, syntax

I would like to plot these following parametrizations:

$$s(\theta)=\sigma+\lambda s_{\nu}(\theta),\quad s_{\nu}(\theta)=\theta\cot(\theta) + i\nu\theta,\quad \theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$$

For more details, please see: [The accurate numerical inversion of Laplace Transform by A. Talbot](https://bura.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/1970/1/TR_61.pdf).
The parameters $\sigma$, $\lambda$, and $\nu$ are adjustable.
The Talbot's contour should looks like these two:
[image: Pic1]
Or
[image: pic2]

My attempt:

```
σ := 1
λ := 1/2
ν := 1
s1 := θ*Cot (θ) + (I ν θ)
eqn := σ + (λ s1), Assumptions -> -Pi <= θ <= Pi
ParametricPlot[{Re[eqn], Im[eqn]}, {f, -5, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Sorry, I can't give further attempt since I'm not really familiar with Mathematica. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Use Set (=) instead of SetDelayed (`:=`) for assignments to constants. 2) `Assumptions` is an option of only certain functions. You can't use it that way. Didn't you see the error when you tried to execute your code? 3) Functions in MMA enclose their parameters in `[]`, so `Cot[theta]` and not `Cot(theta)`. 4) The variable in ParametricPlot should be the same as in your equation, i.e. theta, not `f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from here:

```
σ = 1;
λ = 1/2;
ν = 1;
s1 = θ Cot[θ] + I ν θ;
eqn = σ + (λ s1);
ParametricPlot[{Re[eqn], Im[eqn]}, {θ, -3.5, 3.5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plot from code above]

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: In the current version, I would use `ReIm[eqn]` within `ParametricPlot[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Some bells and whistles.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since the "parameters ... are adjustable" use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{s1, θ, eqn},
  s1 = θ*Cot[θ] + I*ν*θ;
  eqn = σ + (λ*s1);
  ParametricPlot[
   {Re[eqn], Im[eqn]},
   {θ, -Pi, Pi},
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 3.5}, {-4.25, 4.25}},
   AspectRatio -> 1]],
 {{σ, 1}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{λ, 0.5}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ν, 1}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Another wonderful solution. By the way what does `Clear[Global'*"]` do?

Comment: It removes any prior definitions that might potentially interfere with the code, i.e., makes sure you are starting with a clean slate.